# Would Altap Salamander deserve a tag of its own?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would [Altap Salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altap_Salamander) (also known as *Servant Salamander*) deserve a tag of its own or is it not notable enough?

Another two-pane file manager, the free (as in beer) [Total Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander) currently has [52 tagged questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/total-commander).

Sample question

- *[Running Salamander as admin on a per operation basis](https://superuser.com/questions/62227)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the low number of questions that are specifically about [Altap](https://superuser.com/search?q=Altap%20is%3Aquestion) [Salamander](https://superuser.com/search?q=Salamander%20is%3Aquestion) (only three are specifically about Altap and one of those is closed as it is a software recommendation) I would say probably not at this time.

If we could find more than, say, 10 questions that could legitimately benefit from the tag then I would say to go for it but as it stands it is simply adding another tag for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

If it could enhance the question, and make it more readily findable for experts, I say go ahead and create the tag.